# Entity Framework Core 3.0 table self relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a Sql Server database with hundreds of records in contacts. I need to map with EF Core 3.0 my object Contact with this abnormal relationship. The sample object is

```
    class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ContactId
    { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId
    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User
    { get; set; }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string VatId
    { get; set; }

    public string City
    { get; set; }

    public string Address
    { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(36)]
    public Guid? RefContactId
    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RefContactId")]
    public Contact RefContact
    { get; set; }
}
```

The problem: RefContactId is not ContactId ref but is UserId ref. I found the database already done this way.
How can configure/decore my contact object (or Fluent) to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that `RefContactId` refers to the `User` table? How was this class generated?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the class contact by adding a collection.

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ContactId
    { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId
    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User
    { get; set; }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string VatId
    { get; set; }

    public string City
    { get; set; }

    public string Address
    { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(36)]
    public Guid? RefContactId
    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RefContactId")]
    public Contact RefContact
    { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> SubContacts { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in `OnModelCreating` method, I used Fluent API to change the principal key.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SubContacts)
            .WithOne(x => x.RefContact)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.UserId);
```

Comment: I receive an error: the column RefContactUserId is not valid

Comment: There is no RefContactUserId column? if you want to change the name of foreign key use Fluent API, also.